# How can I omit a string without rendering it conditionally?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native

singlePost has data in the form of an object. I'm rendering the content in singlePost as a string from 1 to 10.

However, an empty string is randomly included in the content. Content1 can contain empty or 2 can contain 8.(i.e) empty strings come in content randomly.  if an empty string comes in, I don't want to render the empty content as text.

how can i fix my code?

```
    const Explain = ({navigation, route}) => {
      const {singlePost} = useSelector((state) => state.post);

      console.log(singlePost);

      // singlePost = {
      //   User: {id: 3, nickname: "bill"},
      //   content1: "number1",
      //   content2: "number2",
      //   content3: "bye",
      //   content4: "empty",
      //   content5: "empty",
      //   content6: "empty",
      //   content7: "empty",
      //   content8: "number3",
      //   content9: "empty",
      //   content10: "empty",
      //   }

      return (
        <Ingretext>
          {singlePost?.content1}
          {'  '}
          {singlePost?.content2}
          {'  '}
          {singlePost?.content3}
          {'  '}
          {singlePost?.content4}
          {'  '}

          {singlePost?.content5}
          {'  '}
          {singlePost?.content6}
          {'  '}
          {singlePost?.content7}
          {'  '}
          {singlePost?.content8}
          {'  '}
          {singlePost?.content9}
          {'  '}
          {singlePost?.content10}
        </Ingretext>
      );
    };

    export default Explain;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) in combination with [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to achieve your goal. Something like this:

```js
singlePost = {
  User: {
    id: 3,
    nickname: "bill"
  },
  content1: "number1",
  content2: "number2",
  content3: "bye",
  content4: "empty",
  content5: "empty",
  content6: "empty",
  content7: "empty",
  content8: "number3",
  content9: "empty",
  content10: "empty",
};

const contentOnly = Object
  // Get the keys of the singlePost object
  .keys(singlePost)
  // Get only keys which have the word 'content' in them
  .filter((x) => x.indexOf('content') !== -1)
  // Get data which isn't equal to 'empty' string
  .filter((key) => singlePost[key] !== "empty")
  .map((x) => singlePost[x])
  // Based on your code, I am assuming that you want the end result to be a string, so I am using .join() here
  .join(' ');

console.log(contentOnly);
```

Comment: i tried your code, when i use  console.log('contentOnly:', contentOnly); this result comes: 
contentOnly: content1 content2 content3
but how can i use this result in return (<Ingretext> ??? </Ingretext>)

Comment: `<Ingretext>{contentOnly}</Ingretext>`

Comment: I tried , But number1,
number2 ,bye should be rendered, but content1 content2 content3 is rendered.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Accidentally returned the keys instead of values. I have updated my code

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `reduce` to get the none-empty content:

```js
let singlePost = {
  User: {
    id: 3,
    nickname: "bill"
  },
  content1: "number1",
  content2: "number2",
  content3: "bye",
  content4: "empty",
  content5: "empty",
  content6: "empty",
  content7: "empty",
  content8: "number3",
  content9: "empty",
  content10: "empty"
};
let contents = Object.keys(singlePost).reduce((acc, key) => {
  if (key.includes("content") && !singlePost[key].includes("empty")) {
    return [...acc, singlePost[key]];
  }
  return acc;
}, []);
console.log(contents);
```